# Clean up child threads when main thread terminates

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I'm finding myself trying to write something like this:

```
main = do t1 <- forkIO (forever io)
          t2 <- forkIO (forever io)
          forever io
          `finally` traverse_ killThread [t1,t2]
```

But `t1` and `t2` can't be accessed in `finally` because it's outside the monad.

Since here the IO actions are run forever, my main concern is giving the threads a chance to exit cleanly in the event of a user interruption or an `IOException` in the last IO action.

I'm aware that packages like `async` and `threads` are great for this, but is it possible to do this easily with the basic concurrency primitives?

BTW, it'd be nice to have the runtime automatically send `killThread` to all child threads. When wouldn't you want that?

Answer (score 2):

Just realized that there is no problem including the `finally` in the monadic code block.

```
main = do t1 <- forkIO (forever io)
          t2 <- forkIO (forever io)
          forever io `finally` traverse_ killThread [t1,t2]
```

I'm not marking this question as answered in case someone spots something wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to kill the child threads because the Haskell runtime kills them when the main thread terminates anyway. Normally, you write code in main to wait for the child threads to complete before completing itself.

Comment: I agree with you that the usual pattern would be for the main thread to wait for the child threads to terminate. But even if it waits, what happens when the main thread receives a user interruption. How does the runtime kill the child threads? Does it propagate the user interruption exception or does it throw a `ThreadKilled` exception to them? I'd like to get access to the exception within the child threads so that I can do some cleanup.